# Copy blob to dropbox using azure functions

Tags: azure, dropbox, azure-functions

I'm looking at creating a function (blob trigger) that copies a blob to a dropbox folder.

Can someone give me pointers of what is needed

I have come across this, but not sure what to specify for connection or for the folder path in dropbox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output binding will look like

```json
{
  "type": "apiHubFile",
  "name": "outputFile",
  "path": "path/{file}",
  "connection": "dropbox_DROPBOX",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

where `path` is the path in drop box and `connection` is a Logic App endpoint. It's easiest to set this up in the Portal: go to your function, then `Integrate` tab, click `New Output`, pick `External File` and follow the wizard.

---

If it's a simple copy of a file from Blob Storage to a folder on Dropbox, the easiest way is to use a Logic App. The workflow would look something like

[image]

Comment: Ok this should help a lot. Im creating the function in visual studio - will i be able to test and run locally based on the connection being dropbox_DROPBOX? I actually tried the second option you suggested with Microsoft Flow. But found this really hit and miss, like it would not always run when a new blob was added.

Comment: @raklos Try making a test function in the portal and see which connection string it generated. Then copy paste it to your settings in VS.